# How do I install a Lexmark Pro200 printer driver for Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: lexmark

How do I install a Lexmark Pro200 printer driver for Ubuntu 12.10?  My printer only has a wireless network interface.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Printers app
2. Click Add.
3. Select Network Printer
4. Wait about 2 secs for it to show up.

If it doesn't show you, enter the IP address of the printer and hit the Find button.

Ubuntu has always found my printers with no trouble at all.